# Is it possible to use a Display Suite Code Field in Views?

Tags: views, display-suite

I've created a code field in Display Suite to to manage the display of a file (the file entity has a few fields per file).

Is it possible to use this same Display Suite code field in Views when creating a list of nodes for display?  I know I can do the same thing in a php field, but I'd rather not have to manage different code in different places to get to the same end result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using Views fields, just use the Content -> Display Suite view modes in the view, that way you can just render the DS view mode with the custom field of the returned nodes in views.